# jQuery - doesnt submit data on enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to work with a chatroom and some users would like a feature to submit on enter.

I current have this code:

Form html:

```
<form id="send-message-area" name="send-message-area" method="post" action="">
    <textarea id="sendie" name="sendie" maxlength = '255'></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="sendieButton" id="sendieButton" value="Send" />
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

$("textarea").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        //$("form").submit();
        $("form").trigger("submit");
    }
});

});
```

However when hitting enter it does indeed submit, however it doesn't send any data with it.
It works just fine when pressing the submit button.

I already tried `$("form").submit();` but it does the exact same.

EDIT:

I think the problem lays in my PHP.

```
if(isset($_POST['sendieButton'])){

    $fromID = $brugernavn;
    $fromMsg = $_POST['sendie'];

    sendMsg($fromID, $fromMsg);

};
```

However when changing to check for $_POST['send-message-area'] it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Why you not doing like this `$("form").submit();`

Comment: Did you make sure you only have one `form` element?

Comment: I tried $("form").submit(); but it did the exact same. Haim777, Yes I only have 1 form element

Comment: There's no `action` in your form. Are you sure that clicking on `submit` is actually submitting the form ?

Comment: instead of `event.keyCode`, try `event.which`

Comment: Yes the submit button does work - The action is on the same page (Submitting without refreshing whole page)

Comment: @AmitSoni - The enter function works well, it's the form.submit which doesn't pass the values

Comment: The action is on the same page.. can you pls elaborate on that ? Doing a Form submit will do a full page refresh, if you don't want to refresh the page, you should actually use Ajax

Comment: Can't reproduce http://jsfiddle.net/z0hxxsgr/

Comment: Can you also attach the full js code and complete html page?

Comment: Did you try $(this).closest("form").submit()?

Comment: As your form doesn't have any `action`, it's submitting those values to the URL from which your Form.html is loaded in the first place, is your PHP code addressing the same URL ?

Comment: @Arkantos - It was a problem with my PHP, problem is solved.. Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button value will not be submitted until you click on it. So either you trigger its click event

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $("textarea").keyup(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13){
            //$("form").submit();
            $("#sendieButton").trigger("click");
        }
    });

});
```

or check only textarea value isset or not in PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['sendie'])){

    $fromID = $brugernavn;
    $fromMsg = $_POST['sendie'];

    sendMsg($fromID, $fromMsg);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for name of the textarea not the button

```
if (isset($_POST["sendie"])) {
    $fromMsg = $_POST['sendie'];   
}else{  
    echo "no sendie";
}
```